Concept “different first integrals” Intuition
During my first lecture about partial differential equations the following concept was introduced:
Let $\phi_{1},..,\phi_{n}$ be first integrals, than we call these first integrals different if there does not exist a function $g: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi_i = g(\phi_{1},…,\phi_{i-1},\phi_{i+1},…,\phi_{n})$.
But then this condition of being different first integrals was expressed in terms of the rank of the Jacobian matrix. I was very confused and did not manage to write it down because I got lost in thought.
Can somebody explain this please? Or maybe give a hint or a link to the theory?
The definition of first integrals is:
Given a normal system of differential equations of $n$ equations and $n$ unknown functions, a first integral of the system is a function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every solution of the system there exists a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(x,\phi_{1}(x),…,\phi_{n}(x))= c$.

Can you apply the chain rule to the $g$ equation? Do you see that this gives a left kernel vector of the Jacobian of the $\phi$ system, where the coefficients are $1$ and the partial derivatives of $g$? Do you know that a matrix with non-trivial kernel vectors can not have full rank?

I think OP is confusing few things.

It is not Jacobian , it is Wronskian
It is not "Different" , it is "Independent"
It is not rank , it is Determinant (though rank will play a role too , in general)
I see only independent variable $x$ , making me wonder whether it is not "Partial Differential Equations" , rather it is "Ordinary Differential Equations" or it is "System of Ordinary Differential Equations"

The term "First Integral" is historically covering the term "Solution" because in early times , most equations had simple forms where the Solution was to integrate.
[[ More here & here & here ]]
When a System of Differential Equations has some Solutions , we would like to know whether those Solutions are "Different" or "Same" : that is technically known as "Independence"
Commonly , we make the Wronskian Matrix & calculate the Wronskian Determinant which must be Non-Zero to indicate Independence.
[[ More here & here & here ]]
In general , Jacobian is used when we have "Change of Variables" like converting $(x,y,z)$ to $(u,v,w)$ : the Jacobian uses First Order Partial Derivatives. It is involved in the Integrals. Extending that , we get the Hessian where Second Order Partial Derivatives are involved.
[[ More here & here & here ]]
I think all this will clear the confusion which OP seems to have.

You have that wrong, functional dependence of some functions does indeed imply linear dependence of their derivatives, which can be expressed via the rank of the Jacobian. Also, there are no solutions involved, thus no Wronskian. Also note that the first sentence gave PDE as topic, why did you put this question into an ODE context?

I think OP is confused , I gave enough web-links ( which OP asked for ) to figure out what was going on in the Class at that moment , @LutzLehmann , where I think ODE was the topic , though OP may confirm/clarify after reading this answer. I already mentioned "why I put this question into ODE context" when I said "I see only independent variable $x$ , making me wonder whether ...." , more-over I mentioned "rank will play a role too" , though it is not clear what the teacher said at that moment. All of this is my guess-work to unconfuse the OP , not rigorous overview of the "unknown" topic.

I speculate that the first topic as or after introduction is the method of characteristics where you start with a first order PDE and try to find as many as possible first integrals for the Lagrange system. I do not see what you see as confusion, the question in itself is quite straight-forward.

Adding the last para from OP which contains "system of differential equations of $n$ equations and $n$ unknown functions" will make it even more towards what I think , @LutzLehmann , It is not PDE , it is System of ODE : Except $x$ , I do not see more independent variables here.

No, that is just a supplement/appendix on where the "first integral" functions come from. The question itself is on the relation of functional and linear dependence or independence of multivariate functions and their derivatives. There is in no case a linear DE involved.

OP made no "Explicit" reference to (A) dependence or independence (B) multivariate functions (C) Independent variables like $u,v,w,y,z$ , though OP did refer to (D) "Different first Integral" , where I suspect "Different" refers to "Dependence" or rather "Independence". Beyond that , I think OP has to check , @LutzLehmann , to let us know what the Issue/Confusion is. When OP says that the answer is too much off target , then I can either delete it or refine it accordingly.

You have the wrong idea about "first integrals". These are constants of motion for  all solutions of some ODE system, $\phi_i(x(t))=C$ for all solutions of an autonomous system $\dot x(t)=F(x(t))$ (add $\dot x_0=1$ in the non-autonomous case). Note that the $phi_i$ are by necessity multi-dimensional in the general system case. I'll concede that the last paragraph is indeed a mess, but the concept "first integral" is well-established, no historical reconstruction necessary. The question apart from the last paragraph is completely clear.

The OP may still turn up to contradict me , though I think a fortnight has gone by without rejecting my suspicion that "ODE Summary" was given to "Introduce PDE" in the Class , @LutzLehmann , Maybe.

@Prem In the following days I will answer your questions, I have not forgotten about it. (So I'm asking you for a bit more patience). Thanks in advance for your understanding.
